# Duplicate precedence - based on date of question or answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253129/error-c2733-second-c-linkage-of-overloaded-function) a few years ago, didn't receive any responses and eventually solved it myself, posting that solution as an answer.

Today I got a notification that someone has suggested it is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775209/resolved-errors-while-compiling-in-visual-c-2008-after-installation-of-ms-p). Looking at it, that *question* predates mine by quite some time, but my *answer* predates the one with the same info on the other thread.

Which should be closed as a dupe of which?

Comment: The date plays no role actually. The question with the better answer should be chosen as duplicate.